# Custom options vs attributes in Magento

Tags: magento

What is the actual difference between custom options and attributes? Or are custom options actually attributes that get created when you configure the custom option?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Magento Attribute**:-
An **attribute** in Magento is defined as any property of a Catalog Category (Entity Type ID - 3), Catalog Product (Entity Type ID - 4), Customer (Entity Type ID - 1), Customer Address (Entity Type ID - 2), Order (Entity Type ID - 5), and some more. These include Product ID, Product Title, SKU, Image, Description, Customer First Name, Customer Last Name, and so on.

All the attributes are stored in the Database Table "`eav_attribute`", and all these attributes depend upon their Entity Types, which are stored in the DB Table "`eav_entity_type`".

A store owner can add as many additional attributes as desired. These can be grouped into attribute sets, so similar products can be created with the same attributes. If you sell TVs, shoes, books, and power tools you could create four attribute sets - one specific to TVs, one for shoes, one for books, and one for power tools. When adding new power tool Products to your Catalog, you simply select the “power tool” attribute set, and the appropriate fields are added for this Product. You can check [this link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields) to know how to Create Attributes in Magento.

**Magento Custom Options**:-
Only Catalog Products (and no other Entity Types) use the concept of Custom Options, which are stored in the DB Table "`catalog_product_option`".

Magento Custom Options enable the customers to add new options (non-stock specific) to the Magento product before adding it to the shopping cart. It allows to increase the product price or to gather extra information from the customer such as product length (custom option can be just a drop down of probable lengths provided by the store), a name to engrave (custom option can be a text field) or an image to print on it (custom option needs to be an upload file field).

Magento Custom options are similar to attributes but they must be filled in by a customer rather than an admin. But which all options can be filled by the customer, is totally dependent upon the admin, as he is maintaining the available Custom Options of the Products.

Comment: Hey this is a very good answer, however the confusion for me searching has been "options for the options", i.e. suppose a custom options is a dropdown list or even a "list" (these terms are so generic searching for answers is difficult, believe me).  Where are these dropdown options or especially list options stored?

Comment: @OliverWilliams - Some of these list options are stored in DB and some of them are hard-coded in Magento core code base.