# Want to add custom option from the frontend of magento

Tags: magento

I want to add a button on product view page. By clicking on that button, there will appear two text box fields which are custom options. When I open that product from the backend, I can find that there are custom options which I added, but I need to view it in the frontend by clicking the button only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **Products are added by the administrator, and are fully controller also by the Administrator**. Only thing is that you (as a customer) can only see the custom options which are available for a particular product (and as provided by the admin).

In your particular case, go to the proper Admin page (Edit / Add a new Product and go to its "**Custom Options**" tab). Now provide options for two text fields, with two different labels, and then save that product. Now if you go to the front-end to view that product, you will find the product details, along with the two custom options added from the admin section.

Also if you want to add a button in the front-end of each product view page, which when clicked will show the custom options, then you need to create a button & write a JavaScript for opening the container of the Custom Options.

Hope it helps.

---

**Edit:-**
First find out the full HTML section of the Custom Options, or in other words, the HTML container of the Custom Options in the Product view page. Provide a unique "`id`" to the container "`DIV`" element and make that element hidden. Also provide the HTML button anywhere in the view page, and call the unique ID of the "`DIV`" element in the "`onclick`" event of the button. A simple code snippet will be like:-

```
<div id="any_unique_id" style="display: none;">
    // Whole Custom Options
</div>
<button onclick="$('any_unique_id').show();">Click here to view the Custom Options</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the help. but if it is possible for you to tell how to use the javascript to show the custom options with a button.

Answer (score 0):

checkout Knowledge Craving [2nd part's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870332/magento-custom-options-vs-attributes/4870537#4870537)

Comment: ya i understand......

but what should i do if i want to add custom option from the front end with a button.when i will click on that button there will two text box appear on the frontend. also on the backend when i open that product i can see two text field options on the custom option.

help me please....or i will sacked by BOSS....